# Can I specify HTTP method in Django generic ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, http

ListCreateAPIView in Django includes HEAD and OPTIONS methods. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `http_method_names` attribute like

```
class YourApiView(ListCreateAPIView):
    
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', ...]
```